# How to start the kiwi browser always incognito mode?

Tags: applications, browser, privacy

I want to start the kiwi browser always in incognito mode.
How can i do it ?

I know there is a option to click on incognito mode, But I want it to start with incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

The method might not be optimal but it works for me.

1. Open the app drawer, Long press on Kiwi browser icon.
2. Two choices will appear: New tab and New Incognito tab. Long press on New Incognito tab to create a shortcut.
3. Optional: If you there is a Kiwi browser on your home screen, delete it. Edit the shortcut name from Incognito tab to Kiwi Browser if your launcher allows it.

Caveats: If you open Kiwi Browser from the app drawer,  it will open a new tab not a new incognito tab.